# Batch renaming files to remove prefix and characters in the middle of file name

Tags: windows, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files on MS DOS and need to remove the prefix "Q0card-" and also remove a string ".psd" before the file extension.

```
Q0card-Aurora.College.psd.png
Q0card-RedBullRacingHonda.psd.png
Q0card-ROKiTVenturiRacing.psd.png
Q0card-WaltDisneyWorldResort.psd.png
Q0card-Zenseact.psd.png
```

Is there a way to easily do this with a MS DOS command or a batch file script?  I tried using jren.bat but the documentation and examples is lacking and not giving me enough info nor guidance.